# cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lXss

Tags: cygwin, ld, wordnet

I am trying to install WordNet with cygwin.
But Getting the following error during make

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/cygdrive/d/VaiVocabulary/vaiLinuxFinal/wordNet/WordNet-3.0/src'
gcc  -g -O2   -o wishwn.exe  wishwn-tkAppInit.o wishwn-stubs.o -L../lib -lWN -L/usr/lib -ltk8.5 -L/usr/lib -ltcl8.5 -lX11 -lXss -lXext -lXft -lXrender -lfontconfig -lexpat -liconv -lfreetype -lz -lbz2 -lX11 -lxcb -lXau -lXdmcp    -ldl
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lXss
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lXext
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lXft
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lXrender
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lfontconfig
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lexpat
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lfreetype
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lbz2
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:223: recipe for target `wishwn.exe' failed
```

It seems linking error. What would I have to do to resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

It definitely looks like you are missing those libraries. Rerun Cygwin's Setup.exe and when you get to the package selection screen enter your missing dependencies in the 'search' box. For example searching for `Xss` and `Xext` finds both libraries (and their development packages) in the X11 folder while `bz2` is in Libs.